# How to concatenate variable and text to input( ) request under Settings?

Tags: input, view, concatenation, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to create a very simple set of levels for Trading View in PineScript. I've already successfully plotted these levels, now I'd like to add text above the plotted the levels. I'd like to add text next to these levels in the Settings Input. I can easily create a standard input(" ", "4808 Label") but I'd like the 4808 to automatically show up in the Settings before the word label as these levels change each day.

```
support_color = input.color(color.rgb(255, 128, 255), "Support Color", inline="Support")
offset = input.int(defval = 50, title = "Offset Labels")
hline_smajor_1 = 4808.0
hline(hline_smajor_1, "(major)", color=support_color, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=3)

**// this next line is where I get the following errors. I understand I'm trying to concatenate a variable and text but don't know how to work around these errors**
// Error at 65:64 Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr0'=' Label'. An argument of 'literal string' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.
// Error at 65:32 Cannot call 'input' with argument 'title'='call 'str.tostring' (simple string)'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.

**hline_smaj_text_1 = input(" ", str.tostring(hline_smajor_1), + " Label")**

label hline_smaj_label_1 = label.new(bar_index + offset, hline_smajor_1, hline_smaj_text_1, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)

label.delete(hline_smaj_label_1[1])

// Dummy plot to hide price scale
plot(0, display=display.none)
```

If these values will stick around for the next day, say 'hline_smajor_1' changes to '4810.0', I assume the code will revert back to the " " default for input. If this is not the case, I'd like to have the previous days notes removed since I'll be using the same variable 'hline_smajor_1', 'hline_smajor_2', etc

I'm sure there is a simple work around but I'm stuck and haven't been able to find anything online after an hour plus of searching.

```
hline_smaj_text_1 = input(" ", str.tostring(hline_smajor_1), + " Label")
```

Under Settings I'm expecting:

4808 Label and the default value to be blank and the 4808 to be auto-populated from my variables

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, dynamic label is not possible. Only constant values are allowed.